# Vector drawable color is not getting updated inside onBindViewHolder

Tags: android

I am setting background color of vector drawable dynamically using:

```
Drawable mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, item.getCategoryIconId());

            mDrawable.setColorFilter(new
                    PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, item.getCategoryColorId()), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
            holder.expenseCatIcon.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
```

But while setting color to same Vector drawable again inside onBindViewHolder it gets updated for every row of recyclerview where I am using that drawable.

[image]

Above I added the view of which I am talking about, I have a different activity where I can create items like "food", "gult", "loot" and "ffd" etc.
And I made sure that the resource color id is different, result from Log:

> Name:food Color:2131623945
>   Name:gult Color:2131624100
>   Name:loot Color:2131624174
>   Name:ffd Color:2131624084

What my understanding is that **when I am setting the color filter to vector drawable the color comes in last gets applied to that vector drawable and that results in same color for all the same drawable resource.**

Is there any thing I could do to make this work?

Comment: either your color in not fetching exactly or your method to change color is not working, you should try it by using hex value of your color like this.....ivIcon.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 179, 147, 59));

Comment: the color is coming fine..pls see the edit

Comment: you need to `mutate` your `Drawable` first

Comment: yes mutating the Drawable worked, thanks @pskink

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

As the views get recycled so your applied changes show for all drawables in onBindHolder. Maybe add some conditional statements if you want a different output.

Comment: Yeah you are right view is getting recycled..thinking of an alternative/condition